# How to get facebook's user's information with FB.login()

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

In my code, I am using the "FB.login()" function to log in the user. With the response variable below I have only access to the user's ID. Is it possible to retrieve the user's name and email?
This is my code:

```
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
            appId: '531991481003168',
            cookie: true,
            xfbml: true,
            version: 'v5.0'
        });

        FB.AppEvents.logPageView();

    };

    (function (d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));


</script>

<script async defer src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function statusChangeCallback(response) {

        if (response.status !== "connected") {
            FB.login(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            });    
        }
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#btn-facebook").on("click", function() {
            FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
                statusChangeCallback(response);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Facebook's documentation it's really confusing and I can't find this simple thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Login, use [`FB.api`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/FB.api) to get additional data:

```
FB.api('/me', {fields: 'name,email'}, (response) => {
    document.getElementById('response').innerHTML = 'Hello ' + response.name;
});
```

Example: https://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

Comment: that helped thanks, but now I can't access the email data It just doesn't appears on "response".

Comment: you did not authorize with any additional permission. check out the example, you have to set up your FB.login function correctly with the permissions you need.